# Illustrator strange artifacts on curves

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

After creating a path with rounded corners in Illustrator, I added a dashed stroke and aligned it inside the path (but the problem is the same when aligning outside).
Strangely I ended up with a lot of strange 'glitches' (?) along the path:

[image]

When aligned centered, the stroke looks neat and sharp:

[image]

I've tried changing stroke properties but nothing really helps.
Has anyone ever experienced similar behaviour? How can I get those sharp strokes back?

**To create this symmetrical shape I first created the left half, copied it, reflected the copy and united the both parts with Pathfinder.**

Here's the **actual document** in case someone is interested: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17682405/example.ai

Comment: Try change options to this (on the right side of the screenshot) - http://i.stack.imgur.com/XUSFy.png

Comment: I've never seen or heard of such a thing. Is there a raster effect applied to the object? What's the Appearance Panel look like???

Comment: Thanks Ilan, I tried the same thing but unfortunately that option is greyed out.

Comment: Scott, I didn't raster anyhing. The Appearance Panel just mentions the "2pt Dashed Inside".
Here's the actual document in case you're interested: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17682405/example.ai

Comment: Wow. I see it in your file here too.. no rhyme or reason for that. Looks to be some sort of drawing bug. Note it's happening on **every** curve of that path. I can't draw a path, apply the same stroke, and recreate the issue. I'm left to think that path is the problem itself. Was it imported from somewhere else? Other plug ins used? -- for example, if using VectorScribe, maybe it's a bug with that plug in.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) No plug-ins at all. I added this to my original post: "To create this symmetrical shape I first created the left half, copied it, reflected the copy and united the both parts with Pathfinder."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Try these first:

- **Toggle the image preview between the CPU and GPU preview.** This has been reported to possibly correct this issue (View > CPU/GPU Preview)
- Ensure strokes are **not** set to align to the inside. Also reported to address the issue.

---

For this *particular* question......

I found the issue.....

Select the path and **uncheck** `Align to Pixel Grid` on the **Transform Panel** -- Solved.

Apparently it's some sort of drawing bug with Align to pixel grid.

It took me a bit to find this, but the misalignment across the collar started me thinking... why is that stroke not sitting on the path???  And that lead to the `Align to Pixel Grid` Setting.

In **CC2017**.. you need to check the little button all the way to the right of the **Control Bar**:

[image]

<sub>(Thanks to @cyptus for pointing that out)</sub>

---

## If **none of this helps** . . .

You need to **contact Adobe** to address this technical issue. It may be a direct problem related to *your specific system* which *can not* be solved here.