# illustrator: white pixels in rounded path border

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pixel

i am using adobe illustrator cc 2017 and getting strange white pixels at my rounded path borders:

[image]

when i export the file for web or open the saved pdf in any browsers these pixels are not shown.
how can i prevent this and where does it comes from?

EDIT: I think this is a issue with my illustrator installation, these transparent (not white) pixels appear at every rounded paths, doesnt matter which file i open.

Comment: Try zooming in really close, it almost looks like a path that is not outlined. If you press cmd-y or ctrl-y, are they still there. That command shows a wireframe version of the art board.

Comment: this is already at zoom 8500%, but also appears at zoom 0. it's not there in the wirefirme few, the path itself is correct, see: https://i.imgur.com/xsL0nzC.png - if i draw over the pixels with a pen they are drawn out. if i change the color of the fill of the path, the color changes but the strange white pixels keep in place...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/illustrator-rounded-corner-inside-stroke-artifacts

Comment: this option has moved in CC 2017 to the top right corner under the search, but the to icons for pixel grid alignment are both switched off

Comment: when i turn on "view -> overprint preview" the corners looks nice without these lags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution! i had to switch to "View -> CPU Preview" - works fine now (i am using an i7-7600u without dedicated gpu if this matters)

thanks to [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/illustrator-rounded-corner-inside-stroke-artifacts/39058?noredirect=1#comment137617_39058)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a layer under or over it that has another element (which may or may not be hidden).

If that's not the case, it looks like it might be trying to connect the path points into a shape on its own, hence the straight line between them and what looks to be a really dodgy gradient as the "fill".

Comment: thanks, but sadly there is no other layer.. and if i change the path like this for example, the strange pixels comes with it: https://i.imgur.com/B1yVtQ4.png - how can i prevent illustrator from connecting the paths "at its own" ?