# Illustrator showing objects with jagged edges, but fine upon export

Tags: adobe-illustrator

has anyone experienced this? Seemed to happen just randomly one day.
[image]

Comment: Does this address the issue? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/illustrator-rounded-corner-inside-stroke-artifacts/39058#39058

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrator strange artifacts on curves](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/illustrator-strange-artifacts-on-curves)

Answer (score -1):

Go to view and turn on Overprint View. That should do the trick, its just showing you a more sharper pixels for easier manipulation of them