# Why is this happening to my text / picture?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have just opened a blank document in adobe illustrator, added this picture and text yet I am getting random triangles / lines through it when I move it around...

[image]

there are no hidden shapes etc, this is a new document.

Comment: I'd guess it's a bad font

Comment: Or the GPU settings?

Comment: Maybe this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/illustrator-rounded-corner-inside-stroke-artifacts

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same splintering to triangles in a CAD program. The new version started to use more graphic card power without giving a possiblity to stick in old graphics mode. My ancient card had some of the needed functions badly implemented. The fixing options were:

- use the old version
- buy a modern graphics card which is listed to be compatible

Illustrator has in the preferences a possiblity not to use the Graphics Processing Unit performance feature. Deselecting GPU Performance can fix your problem. Of course the graphic performance will feel sluggish with complex images.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like relics left over from flattening or tracing.

I'm guessing the shoe graphic has some mess attached to it. Unlock everything, get it on same layer, expand then add stroke to everything to see all items in your file.

If there is truly nothing there causing that distortion than start fresh, introducing and checking each element as you bring it in.

If you do see unwanted artifacts than delete them.