# Illustrator CC paintbrush

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I place a saved image (eps, pdf or ai) from Illustrator CC on an InDesign document or open it in Photoshop, the brush strokes lose the paintbrush effect. See examples. It always looks like a brush stroke in Illustrator but when placed it always looks smooth. Can I retain the effect of paintbrush bristles?
[image: Left is how I want it to look. Right is how it turns out]

Comment: Are there *actually* brushes applied to the stroke or it it perhaps the GPU preview bug? [SEE HERE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/illustrator-rounded-corner-inside-stroke-artifacts) It looks to me like it's the bug.. which wont' show in InDesign or Photoshop because it's not *actually* part of the artwork.

Answer (score -1):

You must use **Expand Appearance** before export it.

So, it will be opened exacly as it is shown in Illustrator.

See the image bellow.

[image]

Comment: I **disagree**. There should be *no need* to expand brushes in Illustrator [SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLR2q.jpg)

Comment: Ken is not geting to do it the right way. I know there is no need to expand the strokes. I am showing a way to do it with no doubt. The methot I explained here really works. @Scott

Comment: Well what is "the right way" then?? Maybe I'm missing something. To be fair.. *rasterizing* everything would also work. That doesn't mean it's a great solution.